# how to format NSDate from coreData and display it correctly

Tags: ios, core-data, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

i want to format my date which comes from coreData.
i am getting the date from coredata with this line of code:

```
[[managedObject valueForKey:@"presentationDate"] description]
```

i know that i can format the NSDate with NSDateFormatter.

here is my code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd.MMM.yyyy"];

NSDate *date = (NSDate *) 
[[managedObject valueForKey:@"presentationDate"] description];

NSLog(@"theDate: |%@| \n", [dateFormat stringFromDate:date]);//output is null
```

The output ist null. I cant find the right way to put out the date correctly. please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If presentationDate is a DATE and its class is DATE in the managed object, then the error is here

```
NSDate *date = (NSDate *) 
[[managedObject valueForKey:@"presentationDate"] description];
```

You'd better writing this

```
NSDate *date = (NSDate*) [managedObject valueForKey:@"presentationDate"] ;
```

Answer (score 2):

[`-description`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/description) method always returns `NSString` that describes object.
So, you mustn't call it when getting object from core data.